# Is this the right way to upload files on github?

Tags: github

I am quite beginner on GitHub so I got a question after a lot of trying:

To upload a file after creating a Repo for exp: a style.css file

```
touch style.css
git add README
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/Hello-World.git
git push origin master
```

then css.file is sent onto my github account but still emtpy and **to put my css code in it on github Repo page click on style.css and edit and copy paste my all css codes.**

Does it work really only this way?

Comment: Everytime you make changes to a file and you want it on your github repo, you have to add it, commit it and then push it.```git add styles.css git commit -m "added styles" git push origin master```

Comment: Oh my God. OMFG, to be more exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

before `git push origin master` you need to add the style.css file to your local repo:

```
git add style.css
```

and them summarize your changes in a commit with a commit message:

```
git commit -a -m 'added style.css'
```

and then push your changes from your local repo to the remote one:

```
git push origin master
```